# How to display one element based on condition in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have a form to display details of product on screen, onclick of edit button i want to hide all details and display editable components instead. i have used angular 2  *ngIf condition but it is not working

```
<p *ngIf="isEditable">Product 1</p>
<input type="textbox" *ngIf="!isEditable" />

edit() {
   isEditable=true;
 }
```

screen is loaded with label but on click of edit button both lable and textbox are displaying. i just want textbox and hide label on click. how can i do this.

Comment: did you tried using ChangeDetectionStrategy ?

Comment: It should be `this.isEditable = true`. You're missing the `this`

Answer (score -1):

You are right, only thing inside the function use this.editable

```
edit() : void {
   this.isEditable=true;
 }
```

Comment: i am using this.isEditable only inside edit(). still i am facing issue

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: dom is loaded with lable, on edit click im binding textbox on demand using edit(). then label already added to DOM .

Comment: produce a stackblitz/plunker for the issue

Comment: @Jota.Toledo it does not, void instead of boolean